# Windows Hello API

Tags: java, windows, web-applications, windows-hello

I would like to use Windows Hello Face and Fingerprint API in my web application.

The websites I found show C# coding but my web application is developed in Java.
How do I integrate Windows Hello Face and Fingerprint API in my Java web application?

Answer (score 3):

I also wonder, but I have find out, that Windows Hello is based on Intel solution Real Sense https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense also for Linux. I dont see, that they have Java API, but I would say, that java native wrapper can be created for library. There is also documentation https://software.intel.com/sites/products/realsense/person/developer_guide.html#3.2.3_Person_Recognition. I have not tried it yet, but I think, it can be good point of start.

this also may help us to get stuff working https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-sample-facial-recognition-using-intel-realsense-sdk